# DOM event does not bubble in off-DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have a DOM element that is not in DOM yet and I want to trigger a DOM event.

The event does not bubble up. But with jQuery, it does. Which seems weird for me.

This behaviour is reproducible in **Safari and Chrome** (in Firefox it works correctly — the event bubbles up):

```
var log = function(event) {console.log('Clicked on div', event);};

// Create DOM element.
var div = document.createElement('div');
// Don't append it to DOM. Though it works if we append it there.
// document.body.appendChild(div);
div.innerHTML = '<a id="outer"><span class="inner">yo</span></a>';

// Does not work.
div.addEventListener('click', log);
div.querySelector('#outer').click();

// Works!?
$(div).on('click', log);
$(div).find('#outer').click();
```

Does jQuery implement custom event bubbling strategy? Is it browsers who are wrong here?

**edit:** created [a bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=122755)

Comment: Works for me in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/DLmha/

Comment: as I have mentioned in the post, it's cool in firefox.

Comment: Heh, yeah, sorry. Missed that.

Comment: I think you're right. Because jQuery never binds the handler you give it directly to the element, it doesn't need to rely on any native means of triggering the event when doing so manually. So it would just start at the target, see if it was given an event handler via jQuery, and if so, trigger it, then proceed to the `.parentNode` and repeat until the `window` or until something stops propagation.

Comment: So, the question is -- is it browsers who are wrong? Should I file it as a bug because Firefox actually works?

Comment: If you file a bug, base it on your reading of the spec. Here's the [W3C DOM Level 3 Event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#bubble-phase) spec for bubbling. Not sure if this is what they're implementing, but I would guess it's likely. It does define bubbling as ending with the ***defaultView***, so maybe Chrome interprets that as meaning events on detached elements shouldn't bubble. But maybe FF has a different interpretation based on some other text. Maybe HTML5 changed things. Not sure. Take a stab and see what happens.

Comment: The bug apparently has been fixed in all modern browsers since this question was asked. Voting to close as "no-repro".

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with

```
$(div).find('#outer').click();
```

Note that if you go with

```
$("#outer").click();
```

It doesn't work as well. So my bet would be that JQ triggers the click for the div element as well, instead of bubbling with the DOM.

Comment: how are you using $('#outer'), when the div is not in DOM…?

Comment: are you able to get anything out of $('#outer') ?